# How can I find a monitors timing settings?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution, vga

We have two identical monitors. One monitor is connected via HDMI, and the other is using a dumb VGA to HDMI adapter (as the PC only has 1x HDMI and 1x VGA port).

Since Windows is unable to determine the settings of the monitor using the VGA to HDMI adapter, it defaults to a very low resolution, and there are no other resolutions to select.

Using the Intel Graphics Media Control Center, we can add custom resolutions. We created a custom resolution of 1920x1080, with 60hz refresh rate and the image looks better, but due to incorrect timings, the taskbar is cut off, and the image is slightly fuzzy.

Instead we need to add a custom resolution in advanced mode, which means we need to include all of the relevant timing settings, such as horizontal front porch, sync width etc.

How can I get this settings from the monitor connected with HDMI to create a custom resolution for the monitor connected with the VGA adapter?

Comment: For the record ALL monitors have EDID which provides the requested information. Your adapter is blocking windows from reading the info.  Windows dumps the EDID into a registry key, but since you already have answer no need to dig further.

Comment: @cybernard Thank you. I couldn't locate where the data was stored in the registry but with the acronym, "EDID", it would probably be easier to find now.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\HWP326E\4&8861689&0&UID200195\Device Parameters\EDID   The HWP part and the code starting with 4& are based on the installed monitor and you won't have those exact values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a method by using [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).

You can simply select the working monitor at the top left drop down, then select the resolution under "Detailed resolutions" and then click "edit". This will show you all the settings.

[image: Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)]

Edit: Option 2, is a utility from Nirsoft. https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dump_edid.html